# Kafka : connect a producer to a server in Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, apache-kafka

I'm having some issues, trying to connect a producer container with a kafka container.
I will have 3 differents projects, each running in a docker container on the same machine :

- kafka server
- producer
- consumer

At this moment, my Kafka's server is running well and I have just made a producer which i'm trying to send a message (only basic test).

I'm getting this error :
`kafka:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#172.28.0.3:9092 failed: Connection refused`

I checked multiple post/response but I'm kinda lost, I have read I needed the same network so I did it but can't figure what's else I'm missing.

Here is my Kafka server docker compose :

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - pgsql

    pgsql:
        image: 'postgres:13'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-5432}:5432'
        environment:
            PGPASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
            POSTGRES_DB: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            POSTGRES_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-pgsql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                [
                    "CMD",
                    "pg_isready",
                    "-q",
                    "-d",
                    "${DB_DATABASE}",
                    "-U",
                    "${DB_USERNAME}"
                ]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s

    zookeeper:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
        environment:
            ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
            ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
        ports:
            - 22181:2181
  
    kafka:
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper
        ports:
            - 29092:29092
        environment:
            KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
            KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
            KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka:9092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://localhost:29092
            KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
            KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_INTERNAL
            KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        networks:
            - kafka
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
    kafka:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    sail-pgsql:
        driver: local
```

Here my producer :

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
            - proxy
        depends_on:
            - pgsql
    pgsql:
        image: 'postgres:13'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-5432}:5432'
        environment:
            PGPASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
            POSTGRES_DB: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            POSTGRES_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-pgsql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "${DB_DATABASE}", "-U", "${DB_USERNAME}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
    proxy:
        external:
            name: server_kafka
volumes:
    sail-pgsql:
        driver: local
```

When I inspect the network I see my both container :

```
docker network inspect server_kafka 
[
    {
        "Name": "server_kafka",
        "Id": "6bc8ed3f604da554eeead58dca06ba8dd926673ae9683095de18a56b45bbd70f",
        "Created": "2022-02-21T11:55:31.022965034+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.28.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.28.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "0b4c79952626cc79e757681137523ad918b802945d82df501f7f1ad1141ca841": {
                "Name": "microservice-1_laravel.test_1",
                "EndpointID": "99398ddf104b8f8ce478a611e6885fba8960fd956c59938cca4fbecc8d7d21c5",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1c:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.28.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c1bf90faa56f61432ad99e11408ea50bfeaf5fcdeca0bfd9791bf28cb9fea835": {
                "Name": "server_kafka_1",
                "EndpointID": "4af2450208622da0550d935332c5451c8c53a07ff10a120fb519f30cfbd157cb",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1c:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.28.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "kafka",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "server",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The doc above is nice.
In my case, I was missing the network for zookeeper in my docker-compose

```
networks:
    - kafka
```